# Calling Remote EJB3 in separate EAR file from JSF in another EAR file on WAS 8

Tags: jsf-2, ejb, ejb-3.0, websphere-8

I'm new to EJB3 and having trouble calling a remote ejb from my JSF managed bean when the two are in separate ear files on the same server (WAS 8). If they are in the same ear file then I have no problems. But I need the call to work across different applications on the same server.

During the EJB injection into the Managed Bean, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: The EJB/BelgianBeerSessionBean EJB reference in the null component in the BeerStoreWebProject.war module of the BeerStoreWebEAR application could not be resolved; nested exception is: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBNotFoundException: EJB with interface com.ejb.view.BelgianBeerSessionBeanRemote not present in application BeerStoreWebEAR
Caused by: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBNotFoundException: EJB with interface com.ejb.view.BelgianBeerSessionBeanRemote not present in application BeerStoreWebEAR
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.HomeOfHomes.getHomeByInterface(HomeOfHomes.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.injection.factory.EJBLinkObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(EJBLinkObjectFactory.java:261)
    at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.injection.factory.EJBLinkObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(EJBLinkObjectFactory.java:167)
```

I'm hoping that someone could help me get to the bottom of this and explain how I should be injecting and looking up a remote EJB if it is in a separate EAR  file.

Here is my setup:

### Project Setup

1) BelgianBeersEJMProjectClient (an ejb client project that contains the interfaces)

```
package com.ejb.view;
public interface BelgianBeerSessionInterface {
    List<Country> getAllCountries();
    void saveCountries(List<Country> countries);
}

package com.ejb.view;
@Remote
public interface BelgianBeerSessionBeanRemote extends
        BelgianBeerSessionInterface {

}
```

2) BelgianBeersEJBProject (containing the ejb implementation)

```
    package com.ejb;
    @Stateless
    public class BelgianBeerSessionBean implements BelgianBeerSessionBeanRemote,
            BelgianBeerSessionBeanLocal {

        public BelgianBeerSessionBean() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public List<Country> getAllCountries() {
                //to be implemented
                return null;
        }
        public void saveCountries(List<Country> countries) {
            //to be implemented
        }
    }
```

Also in the META-INF there is an ejb-jar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar version="3.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">
  <display-name>BelgianBeersEJBProject </display-name>
  <ejb-client-jar>BelgianBeersEJBProjectClient.jar</ejb-client-jar> 
 </ejb-jar>
```

3) BelgianBeersWebProject - contains the jsf app

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BeerStorePageBean {

    @EJB(name="EJB/BelgianBeerSessionBean")
    private BelgianBeerSessionBeanRemote store;
    public BelgianBeerSessionBeanRemote getStore() {
        return store;
    }
    public void setStore(BelgianBeerSessionBeanRemote store) {
        this.store = store;
    }
    private List<Country> countries = null;

    @PostConstruct
    public void populateCountries(){
        System.out.println("Store = " + store);
        countries = store.getAllCountries();    
    }
    public List<Country> getAllCountries() {

        return countries;
    }
}
```

and in the web.xml there is an ejb entry:

```
<ejb-ref>
        <description />
        <ejb-ref-name>EJB/BelgianBeerSessionBean</ejb-ref-name>
        <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
        <home />
        <remote>com.ejb.view.BelgianBeerSessionBeanRemote</remote>
    </ejb-ref>
```

### Deployment Units

```
EAR file 1 (BelgianBeersEARProject.ear) contains:
   1) BelgianBeersEJBProject.jar
   2) BelgianBeersEJBProjectClient.jar

 EAR file 2 (BeerStoreWebEAR.ear) contains: 
   1. BeerStoreWebProject.war
   2. BelginaBeersEJBProjectClient.jar
```

Please could somebody explain to me the correct way of calling a remote EJB which is in a separate EAR file. Please help! I'm tearing my hair out!

Comment: Can anybody tell me the correct way of calling a remote EJB which is in a separate EAR file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [@EJB](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJB.html) annotation (and corresponding `<ejb-ref>` in XML) will only automatically link if the target EJB is in the same application.  From the javadoc:

> If no explicit linking information is provided and there is only one
>   session bean within the same application that exposes the matching
>   client view type, by default the EJB dependency resolves to that
>   session bean.

To link to an EJB in another application, you need to specify a *binding*.  You can do this in several ways:

1. Specify `<lookup-name>targetBindingName</lookup-name>` in the `<ejb-ref>` in ejb-jar.xml.
2. Specify `<ejb-ref name="EJB/BelgianBeerSessionBean" binding-name="targetBindingName"/>` in the `WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xml` file of the WAR module containing the ejb-ref.  See the [InfoCenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/cejb_bindingsejbfp.html) for more information on the format of the binding files.
3. Specify the target binding name during application deployment (that is, do not "use default bindings").

In any case, you're going to need the binding name of the target EJB.  The InfoCenter link above describes both the "classic" WebSphere Application Server binding names and the Java EE 6 standard "java:global" names.  The former can be configured in `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` and the latter cannot (aside from specifying alternate `<application-name>` or `<module-name>`), but it doesn't really matter which you use.  To find which names are being used, it's easiest to start the EJB application and then look for the `CNTR0167I` messages that are printed by the EJB container when it starts (the first one is the "classic" binding):

```
[6/6/13 17:26:04:531 CDT] 00000049 WASNameSpaceB I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the javax.management.j2ee.ManagementHome interface of the Management enterprise bean in the mejb.jar module of the ManagementEJB application.  The binding location is: ejb/mgmt/MEJB
[6/6/13 17:26:04:544 CDT] 00000049 AbstractEJBRu I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the javax.management.j2ee.ManagementHome interface of the Management enterprise bean in the mejb.jar module of the ManagementEJB application.  The binding location is: java:global/ManagementEJB/mejb/Management!javax.management.j2ee.ManagementHome
```